# Кто такая мымра?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

*Наша **мымра*** — помните "Служебный роман"?
Вот я вдруг задумалась: а кто такая вообще эта мымра?
Я знаю, например, кикимору, фурию, мегеру — это все отрицательные мифологические персонажи. Из этого я могу сделать предположение, что мымра — тоже какое-то мифологическое существо, с которым сравнивают не слишком приятную женщину.
А можно узнать поточнее?

Answer (score 3):

Что же касается этимологии ругательства "мымра".
Смысл этого слова, претерпев небольшую трансформацию, ныне практически вернулся к изначальному. Слово *мымра* в народно-областные говоры попадает из коми-пермяцкого "мыныра" — "угрюмый", а из народной речи оно усваивается и литературным языком (около середины XIX в.).
Попав в русскую речь, оно стало означать прежде всего необщительного домоседа (в словаре Даля так и написано: *мымрить — безвылазно сидеть дома*).
Постепенно "мымрой" стали называть и просто нелюдимого, скучного, серого и угрюмого человека. Именно в этом значении адресовал его своей начальнице герой к/ф "Служебный роман".

Answer (score 2):

- **мымра** - так называли когда-то самодельную *тряпичную*, набитую ватой куколку, с грубовато нарисованным личиком... и естественно, красотой не отличавшуюся, поэтому слово и стало синонимом не шибко хорошенькой женщины...  :о)bg

Comment: Так называется река в Ярославской губернии. И что? Не шибко хорошенькая?